# JsonConvert.SerializeObject and handling of Empty Strings

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have an object that is returned from a web service containing empty strings. The object is called `Docs` and the object `Docs.Rows` is a `List<List<string>>` which is then used in the code below as `filteredRows`. When I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, it removes every column that has an empty string. These columns are important.

I've tried these 2 approaches:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filteredRows,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { });

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filteredRows,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include });
```

All columns with empty strings are still being removed. How do I make it keep them?

The filteredRows is also defined as `List<List<string>>`. Can I serialize that into a defined object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide an example program that demonstrates the problem?  A simple example like the following seems to work fine.  Neither null nor empty strings are removed during serialization.  Could it be your filtering process that is actually removing the values?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<string>> rows = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string>
            {
                "A",
                null,
                ""
            },
            new List<string>
            {
                null,
                "B",
                ""
            },
            new List<string>
            {
                "",
                null,
                "C"
            }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[["A",null,""],[null,"B",""],["",null,"C"]]
```